# Overlapping buffer values to create new, dynamic risk profiles around hazardous equipment

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, buffer, dynamic

My question is similar to [Creating buffers with values, and finding areas with high value overlap of these buffers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267027/creating-buffers-with-values-and-finding-areas-with-high-value-overlap-of-these)

Using QGIS, I have several hundred points representing pieces of equipment, each with potentially 3 different lengths of buffer around it in concentric, overlapping circles. Each of these circles represents a hazard originating from the point, and would be filled with the probability of that hazard occurring, for which I also have data.

Each one of these hazard radii may then overlap with other radii from other points, and I'd like to add up the overlapping probability for each overlap, similar to how the link below describes it. However, these risks will change over time, due to equipment wear and sensor degradation, until they are repaired. Due to this, I'd like to be able to have the probabilities filling each buffer be able to change dynamically with time, even if that means it just pulls from the CSV file that is updated whenever the project is loaded.

The solution linked to below manually changes each buffer fill, I think? If I'm being honest I'm not certain if QGIS is the right tool for this, but it seemed like it would be powerful enough for the analysis, but I'm well beyond my skill level, and I don't know enough to judge the other solution.

I am new to QGIS, and I have taken on a project that may be beyond me, and need help to answer the following:

1. Can I have buffers filled with different values, and have them add up and be visible/accessible when they overlap?
   If so, how?
2. Would someone be able to explain the solution given in the below link on a more basic level? I don't recognize most of the terms and ideas cited.

[Creating buffers with values, and finding areas with high value overlap of these buffers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267027/creating-buffers-with-values-and-finding-areas-with-high-value-overlap-of-these)

Answer (score 0):

Went over your link and the solution from @Hornbydd is solid.

Answer to your first question; yes, you can see your link.

Answer to your second question. I suggest you open the `Processing Toolbox` in QGIS. Select via `Processing` (header bar) `> Toolbox`. Or use `Ctrl+Alt+T`. This gives you a search bar where many of those terms can be easily found.

It is a bit much to simplify his solution as it is really clear and short.

If all else fails, I suggest looking it up on YouTube as you have many follow along guides there.

Comment: Thanks for that, it's a big help and it's already helped me to get going.